# Why are there many lines in the graph of random forest?

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-forest

I'm running random forest algorithm on the dataset `Sonar` with the following code:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
library(randomForest)

n <- 208
ntrain <- 100
ntest <- 108
train.idx <- sample(1:n, ntrain, replace = FALSE)
train.set <- Sonar[train.idx, ]
test.set <- Sonar[-train.idx, ]

rf <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = train.set, keep.inbag = TRUE, importance = TRUE)
plot(rf)
```

Could you please explain why we have up to three different lines in the graph? What do the three line represent?

[image]

Comment: Good question, +1. `?plot.randomForest` is not helpful at all. However, it does tell us that `plot.randomForest` invisibly returns the data that is plotted (try `(plot(rf))` with the brackets), which is a three column matrix with columns called `OOB`, `M` and `R`. The first is pretty obviously the out-of-bag error. The other two? No idea.

Comment: Thank you @StephanKolassa, I think the other two are OOB for attributes  `M` and `R` respectively. The only problem remains is which color corresponds to which attribute.

Comment: Ah, yes, those are the target classes. You can deduce which line is which by looking at the return values. The last row of the returned matrix is easiest to map to the lines (`tail(plot(rf))`): the bottom line is `M`, the middle one is `OOB`, the top one is `R`. Do you want to write up a self-answer?

Comment: @StephanKolassa It's best that you write and I accept it because it's your solution to differentiate them ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, `?plot.randomForest` is not helpful at all. However, it does tell us that `plot.randomForest` invisibly returns the data that is plotted (try `(plot(rf)`) with the brackets), which is a three column matrix with columns called `OOB`, `M` and `R`. The first is pretty obviously the overall out-of-bag error. The other two are equally obviously the out-of-bag errors for the two possible classes, which are `M` and `R`.

As to which line corresponds to which column, we inspect the output matrix, specifically the last few lines:

```
> tail(plot(rf))
        OOB          M         R
[495,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
[496,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
[497,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
[498,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
[499,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
[500,] 0.22 0.09259259 0.3695652
```

Thus, the bottom line is `M`, the middle one is `OOB`, the top one is `R`.

Comment: Lurked around just to upvote this. :D